# How to target all input in a particular table row inputs

Tags: jquery

I have a following table structure.

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td>id</td>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Total</td>
  </td>

  <tbody>

   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="" /></td>  
    <td><input type="text" name="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total" /></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="" /></td>  
    <td><input type="text" name="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total" /></td>
   </tr>

  </tbody>
```

How do I get the total value of each rows to total column with jquery. I have tried like this.

```
var total;

$("table tbody tr td input[type=text]").live('keyup blur', function(){

   $(this).parent('tbody tr').find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        var tot +=  $(this).val();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
$("table tbody tr td input[type=text]").live('keyup blur', function(){

   $(this).parent('tr').find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        var tot +=  $(this).val();
   });
});
```

The reason is, `<tbody>` contains all the `<tr>`s. So now updating this way, it selects only the `<tr>`, the current row and selects all the inputs inside it.

Comment: When log the parent object it prints '[td, prevObject: v.fn.v.init[1], context: input.span1 format, selector: ".parent()", constructor: function, init: function…]' Could you please explain this?

Comment: Call me Praveen. Give me a moment. Lemme be back with a fiddle for you.

Comment: Yup. It isn't working. There's something fundamentally wrong with your code.

Comment: Can u explain parent('tr') and parent().parent() targets same tr above example?

Comment: `.parent('tr')` or `.closest('tr')` are same. And, `.parentNode.parentNode` too does the same. What if your `input` is enclosed in another thing by mistake or by script. So in whatever case, this works. That's why I used this. :) Hope you get it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24413/discussion-between-priyanga-and-praveen-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

you can just use parent();

> parent() only travles single level up the DOM tree.

so that should take you to `<tr>`

```
$(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
   ...
});
```

Comment: When log the parent object it prints '[td, prevObject: v.fn.v.init[1], context: input.span1 format, selector: ".parent()", constructor: function, init: function…]' Could you please explain this?